# How to have foreground text with repeat pattern on canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to have a repeated background image with the text foreground but when I add pattern on canvas the text is not visible, here is me code:
HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/03/03/20/23/flowers-4032775__340.png";
        img.height = 10;
        img.onload = function(){
            ctx.font = "30px Calibri";
            ctx.fillText("DEXIE", 10, 50);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
            ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
```

Comment: Draw the text after drawing the pattern.

Comment: Tried, not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the text after drawing the pattern. Changing the fillStyle to what color you want the text to be.

```
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/03/03/20/23/flowers-4032775__340.png";
    img.onload = function(){
        img.height = 10;            
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  // Do you really want to draw the image on the canvas????
        var ptrn = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');

        // Draw pattern first
        ctx.fillStyle = ptrn;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Draw text on top
        ctx.font = "30px Calibri";
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";        // <<== Set text color
        ctx.fillText("DEXIE", 10, 50);

    }
```